# Why does my Android device create a CD-ROM device on my computer?

Tags: usb

When connecting my Android phone (HTC One V) to my PC via USB (in HDD mode), it creates two removable devices for the internal memory and the sd card - as it should.

However, it also creates a CD-ROM device which is always in the "no media inserted" status. Why does it create one and does it have some purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some network-branded devices use a virtual cd-rom device to supply their own tethering software. If your phone's tethering isn't restricted and the device created is empty, I'd say it's safe to ignore it.

Comment: Heh, sounds kind of stupid that it's created even if it's not used at all.

Comment: I agree, it should be removed if it's unused. I think it's there to help operators integrate their own proprietary software easily.

Comment: Just an observation : For me, this stuff was happening on stock rom on u8150 and now when I installed custom roms, CD Roms don't show up anymore.

Comment: @Power-Inside Exactly. This is because custom roms rarely include this kind of bloatware and even more rarely operator customizations.